# A smart way to configure custom cells on table load-up?

Tags: ios, custom-cell

I've got a table view with about 5 different custom cells, which are designed in the storyboard.

Each of these cells has its own dedicated subclass of `UITableViewCell`.

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, I dequeue the cells:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:self.cellArray[indexPath.row] forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

The problem now is, I want to call `configureCell` for each of these cells. Each of my custom cell classes has this method declared and implemented, but the problem is that XCode throws an alert unless I  first cast these cells to their respective classes, because as far as XCode is concerned, these cells are `UITableViewCell` cells.

Individually casting each cell type is doable, but verbose, with lots of `if` and `else if` lines. Is there a smarter way to do this, perhaps using a protocol declaring a method `configureCell`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly, with a protocol. I think it's more flexible than subclassing, but it depends on the semantics of each cell class, and you can always mix and match both approaches.

```
@protocol CellX
- (void)configure:(id)data;
@end

@interface CellA : UITableViewCell <CellX>
@end

@interface CellB : UITableViewCell <CellX>

@end
```

In the cell creation method:

```
NSString *identifier = /* pick one for the indexPath and whatnot */
id<CellX> cell = (id<CellX>)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:<#identifier#>
                                                            forIndexPath:indexPath];

/* cell can be of class CellA or CellB depending on the selected identifier */
[cell configure:<#data#>];
```

In addition to the configuration method you can add to the protocol any property that is shared across cells (like `kind`, `status`, etc. whatever you use to deal with the cells).

Comment: I wound up doing this as it felt the most 'correct' solution and transferable to other similar situations.

Answer (score 2):

Extract `configureCell` to a class BaseCell and let all your custom cell inherit BaseCell. So you can

```
BaseCell *cell = (BaseCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:self.cellArray[indexPath.row] forIndexPath:indexPath];
[cell configureCell];
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. You are presumably suggesting I then override the -configureCell method in the cell subclasses (as they each require a different implementation). But in that case, won't `[cell configureCell]` then just call the implementation in `BaseCell`?

Comment: Of course not. It will invoke the implementation of each `ChildCell`, this called polymorphism, a principle of OO.

Comment: But in your example, when you write `[cell configureCell]`, surely the compiler doesn't know know which subclass of `BaseCell` the `cell` actually is, so how would it know which implementation to use?

Comment: You do know and you do not need to know. It's actually resolve at runtime. If you have a look of cell with debugger, you can see `[cell class]` is the child class, not base one. So you actually send `configureCell` to child class. That's why you need invoke `[super configureCell]` in child implementation if you also want to invoke `BaseCell`'s implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Protocol is a good solution, but I think having a super class that all these custom cell views inherit from is a better one. Put "configureCell" in the super class and override it in the child classes.

```
MyBaseCustomTableCellView *cell =(MyBaseCustomTableCellView*) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:self.cellArray[indexPath.row] forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

And since     "dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:"     creates cell of the type you have defined in the storyboard, calling     "configureCell"     should call the right version of it "in the child class"